# Realm.io API mapping parent object automatically

Tags: swift, realm

I am using Realm and its [REST API's](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#rest-apis) mapping method to map JSON data to my models and their child relationships automatically. It works great, except when I add in a ["To-One"](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-one) relationship on the child models referencing the parent. The mapping goes all out of whack and creates additional entries that don't exist.

The parent model:

```
class Foo: Object {
  dynamic var id = 0
  dynamic var title = ""
  let bars = List<Bar>() // Children

  override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
  }
}
```

The child model:

```
class Bar: Object {
  dynamic var id = 0
  dynamic var title = ""
  dynamic var foo = Foo() // Reference to parent

  override class func primaryKey() -> String {
      return "id        
  }
}
```

Per the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#example) I am mapping the JSON using the convenience method:

```
let foos = JSON["foos"] as! [NSDictionary]
  let realm = Realm()
  realm.write {
    for foo in foos {
      realm.create(Foo.self, value: foo, update: true)
    }
  }
```

I'm aware I could set up the mapping manually, but I want to make use of the convenience method if possible at all. Does anyone know how to set this up?

Comment: `let bars = List<Bars>()` shouldn't be `let bars = List<Bar>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you better use `Inverse Relationships` for ToOne relationship instead.
`Foo` class  will be the same. but you will change `foo` property in `Bar` class, like the following.

```
    class Bar: Object {
        dynamic var id = 0
        dynamic var title = ""
       //dynamic var foo = Foo() // Reference to parent
        dynamic var foo: FOO {
        // Realm doesn't persist this property because it only has a getter defined
        // Define "foo" as the inverse relationship to Foo.bars
        return linkingObjects(Bar.self, forProperty: "bars").first as! Foo
       }

      override class func primaryKey() -> String {
          return "id        
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you - the code `return linkingObjects(Foo.self, forProperty: "bars").first!` is what makes this computed property work. However unfortunately I'm unable to do Realm queries with it, for example: `Realm().objects(Bar).filter("foo == %@", foo)` fails with the error `'Property 'foo' not found in object of type 'Bar'`.

Answer (score 1):

Ismail's answer is correct and I've upvoted it: Realm's query engine only works with properties persisted in the database. If you want to add a persisted backlink property, you'll have to set it yourself.

For example:

```
let foos = JSON["foos"] as! [NSDictionary]
let realm = Realm()
realm.write {
  for foo in foos {
    let persistedFoo = realm.create(Foo.self, value: foo, update: true)
    for bar in persistedFoo.bars {
      bar.foo = foo
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes his answer was correct, I didn't anticipate needing to specify that I'd be performing a query on it. But this solves the problem, thanks!